# How to handle legacy param base URLs in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a legacy PHP application that uses the following URL structure

```
/product_info.php?products_id=YYY
```

where YYY is the product's ID, Product model's id field.

I am now rewriting this application using Rails and for SEO purposes, I have to keep this URL structure for now.

How should I route the above URL to my ProductsController's show action? Should I use Apache's mod_rewrite to rewrite it to /products/:id or can I do it with Rails' router? I would love to be able to use path helpers so that product_path(@product) returns me /product_info.php?products_id=YYY (again for SEO)

Comment: Is this the only such URL structure you need to handle, or are there a lot of different ones?

Comment: There are two such URL structures, including this one. Those are the URLs that have been in search engine indexes for years and we cannot afford changing them to something else for now. Maybe later we can do 301 redirects to reindex them, but not now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually more straightforward than I expected it to be.

First, set up your route:

```
# config/routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/product_info' => 'products#show'
end
```

Since Rails doesn't normally serve PHP files, you'll need to create a MIME type handler for `.php`:

```
# config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register_alias 'text/html', :php
```

Set up your `products#show` action to find the product based on the URL parameter. Since you aliased the `php` MIME type to `text/html`, you don't have to do anything special to render the "PHP" view:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:products_id])
  end
end
```

You'll have to manually create the `product_path` helper method, since you're not using RESTful routes:

```
# app/helpers/products_helper.rb
module ProductsHelper
  def product_path(product)
    "/product_info.php?products_id=#{product.id}"
  end
end
```

Now just create your view:

```
# app/views/products/show.php.erb
<%= link_to @product.name, @product %>
```

Comment: To make it even better for me and restrict the route to php format only I used `match '/product_info' => 'products#show', :constraints => {:format => /php/}` as the route. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Brandan for the excellent post, where ever you might be now.  For future travelers, I found I needed to add `, via: :get` to the end of my match routes or Rails would complain.  Fortunately, I also did __not__ need to preserve my legacy URLs, so I just routed the legacy URLs to a small controller action which redirected to my new URLs with a nice `flash` message.  As a result, I didn't need the path helper method either.